# How to correct my nested for loop in the input_data function?

Tags: c++, file

My Question is that in the input_data() function takes in two parameters, the infile and the statistics_array. This function reads (loops) through the five sets of semester final exam data and populates a portion of the statistics_array.that includes the year,the number of grades and input the number of grades into the grade array that is within the Exam Type Struct I feel as the loop is wrong because at the end when i output all the information is wrong my code and the file contents are below how do i fix this problem?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
struct ExamType {
    string semester_name;
    int year;
    int num_grades;
    float average_grade;
    int grades_above_average;
    int grades_below_average;
    int grades_array[35];
};
void input_data(ExamType[], ifstream&);
void calculate_statistics(ExamType[]);
void print_results(ExamType[]);
void calculate_average(ExamType[], int);
void calculate_above_average(ExamType[], int);
void calculate_below_average(ExamType[], int);
int main()
{
    char make_type;
    ifstream myfile;
    ExamType statistics_array[5];
    myfile.open("infile.txt");
    input_data(statistics_array, myfile);
    calculate_statistics(statistics_array);
    print_results(statistics_array);
}

void input_data(ExamType statistics_array[], ifstream& myfile)
{
    int num_students;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        myfile >> statistics_array[i].semester_name;
        myfile >> statistics_array[i].year;
        myfile >> statistics_array[i].num_grades;
        for (int j = 0; j < statistics_array[i].num_grades; j++) {
            statistics_array[j].grades_array[i];
        }
    }
}

void calculate_statistics(ExamType statistics_array[])
{
    for (int index = 0; index < 5; index++)
    {
        calculate_average(statistics_array, index);
        calculate_above_average(statistics_array, index);
        calculate_below_average(statistics_array, index);
    }

}
void calculate_average(ExamType statistics_array[], int index)
{

    float sum=0;
    float total_average;
    for (int i = 0; i < statistics_array[index].num_grades; i++)
    {

         sum=sum+statistics_array[index].grades_array[i];
    }

    total_average = sum / statistics_array[index].num_grades;
    statistics_array[index].average_grade = total_average;
}

void calculate_above_average(ExamType statistics_array[], int index)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < statistics_array[index].num_grades; i++)
    {

        if (statistics_array[index].grades_array[index] > statistics_array[index].average_grade) 
        {

            count++;
        }
        statistics_array[index].grades_above_average = count;
    }
}
void calculate_below_average(ExamType statistics_array[], int index)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < statistics_array[index].num_grades; i++)
    {

        if (statistics_array[index].grades_array[index] < statistics_array[index].average_grade)
        {

            count++;
        }
        statistics_array[index].grades_below_average = count;
    }

}
void print_results(ExamType statistics_array[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << "Analysis of exams in fall" << " " << statistics_array[i].semester_name << statistics_array[i].year<<endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "The number of grades above average are" << " " << statistics_array[i].grades_above_average<<endl;
        cout << "The number of grades above average are" << " " << statistics_array[i].grades_below_average<<endl;


    }
}
```

And the output:

```
Fall 2013 17
54
96
68
99
35
81
93
32
12
23
45
55
66
77
88
99
100
Spring 2014 10
99
48
22
41
66
80
91
55
83
92
Fall 2014 12
32
12
23
45
51
62
97
38
59
80
91
98
Spring 2015 20
93
41
60
80
90
55
88
99
32
12
23
45
55
66
77
88
99
100
99
98
Fall 2015 15
92
45
61
86
90
55
82
92
32
12
23
45
53
61
73
```

Comment: the inner loop in the `input_data` ... doesn't do anything, you just pull out the value `statistics_array[j].grades_array[i];` ... and nothing. also, I think the indexes are off/wrong/inversed, it should be `statistics_array[i].grades_array[j];`

Answer (score 1):

```
int j = 0; j < statistics_array[i].num_grades; j++) {
        myfile >> statistics_array[i].grades_array[j];
    }
```

the input_data function nest loop code should modify according to above.